# Make all urls in a page absolute from the command line

Tags: command-line, wget, html

I like using `curl` and the command line to process html pages.

Relative urls are a pain.

Is there some easy utility to make all relative urls absolute?

Ideally this would look something like

```
curlabsolute $URL | process
```

Comment: URLs relative to what?

Comment: http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html A relative url when fetching a page from a web server is a url without a hostname or a protocol like `/hello.html`. Using urls like this means that the website can be served from multiple domain names, using different protocols, or easily moved between domains. The downside is that the urls are not a unique identifier of a resource any more, but can only be interpreted together with the base page that you fetched.

Comment: _A relative url when fetching a page from a web server is a url without a hostname or a protocol_ - Hence my question: relative to what?  The base URL is available only to the program that downloads the file.

Comment: Umm... so it might be useful to be able to provide a base URL and interpret all URLs as relative this base URL. In the example above I talked about something imaginary called `curlabsolute` which both fetches a page and absolutize's the URLs this has access to a base url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is **`wget`** utulity:

Let's say we need to download a simple web-page given by `http://www.littlewebhut.com/articles/simple_web_page/`.

The command (the below used *url* is real, the command can be tested "as is"):

```
wget -O simple_page -k http://www.littlewebhut.com/articles/simple_web_page/
```

- `-O` (`--output-document=file`) - The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to `file`.
- `-k` (`--convert-links`) - After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing

---

I will just demonstrate some context html fragment from the mentioned web-page **before** downloading (online varsion):

```
...
<ul>
          <li><a href="/" class="color-menu">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/html/" class="color-menu">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="/css/" class="color-menu">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="/javascript/" class="color-menu">JavaScript/jQuery</a></li>
          <li><a href="/inkscape/" class="color-menu">Inkscape</a></li>
          <li><a href="/gimp/" class="color-menu">GIMP</a></li>
          <li><a href="/blender/" class="color-menu">Blender</a></li>
          <li><a href="/articles/" class="color-menu">Articles</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact/" class="color-menu">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

---

The same fragment **after** downloading, saved in the file `simple_page`:

```
...
<ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/" class="color-menu">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/html/" class="color-menu">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/css/" class="color-menu">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/javascript/" class="color-menu">JavaScript/jQuery</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/inkscape/" class="color-menu">Inkscape</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/gimp/" class="color-menu">GIMP</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/blender/" class="color-menu">Blender</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/articles/" class="color-menu">Articles</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.littlewebhut.com/contact/" class="color-menu">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```